# Given undirected graph G and a MST T of G. Is it possible to design an O(V+E) algorithm to decide if some edge e is contained in a MST of G or not.

Tags: graph-theory

Can I say that if I add e to T and a cycle is formed and if there exists an edge different from e with weight less than e then e cannot be part of any MST?
If not then how can I design such an algo?

Comment: I don't understand the question, if MST is given, then just linearly check all the edges of MST to be equal to $e$ or not. (So this is $O(V)$ complexity)

Answer (score 0):

Just an answer to your first question: No, you can't say that.

Take a look at this tree: Vertex set: $A,B,C$. Edges: $AB$ with weight $w(AB)=1$ and  $BC$ with $w(BC)=3$.

Now add $e=AC$, $w(AC)=2$. Now a cycle is formed and there exists an edge different from $e$ with weight less than $e$. But $e$ is part of the $MST$.